# Can we say that $X \cup Y$ retracts onto $X\ $?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be two topological spaces such that $X \cap Y \neq \varnothing.$ If $Y$ retracts onto $X \cap Y$ then is it true that $X \cup Y$ retracts onto $X\ $?

Our instructor says that it is true because we can take a map which is identity on $X$ and the given retraction on $Y.$ Then on $X \cap Y$ these two definitions match up and we get a well-defined map from $X \cup Y$ to $X.$ But how do I conclude whether this map is continuous? Would anybody have any idea on it? For that I think we need $X$ and $Y$ to be closed in $X \cup Y.$ Then by pasting lemma we are through. Otherwise how do I do that?

Any suggestion regarding this will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's is the topology on $X\cup Y$ here? Are you assuming both $X,Y$ as subspaces of some large space??

Comment: @Sumanta I think $X \cup Y$ has the quotient topology. We can identify $X$ and $Y$ along their intersection. Right? Actually this result is used in a corollary in Hatcher's book which says that $H_n(X \cup (CA - \{p\}, CA - \{p\}) \approx H_n(X,A).$

Comment: @Anacardium Their intersection has no defined topology if the two spaces $X,Y$ aren't part of some larger space. How would you define the intersection of $\mathbb R$ with the metric topology and $\mathbb R$ with discrete topology for example?

Comment: @Noel Lundström we can take $X \sqcup Y$ and then identify points along $X \cap Y.$ Then $X \cup Y$ can be thought of as a quotient space which is better known as **Attaching Space.** Please see my last comment for the sake of clarity.

Comment: That's is a different case. We are thinking $A$ as a subspace of $X$ as well as a subspace of $CA$ using the embedding $f\colon A\ni a\mapsto [a,0]=\frac{A\times [0,1]}{A\times 1}$. In other words, our large space is $X\cup_f CA$.

Comment: @Anacardium Yes, my point is just that you worded it a bit awkwardly in your post. You should have said: "Let $X$ and $Y$ be subspaces of $Z$ ..." otherwise $X \cap Y$ is not defined. It's no big deal though, I understood what you meant.

Comment: @Noel Lundström yeah! I agree. But that is what I meant to say.

Comment: @Sumanta is there any other way to show that $H_n (X \cup (CA - \{p\}), CA - \{p\}) \approx H_n (X,A)\ $? I know that $CA - \{p\}$ deformation retracts onto $A.$ So the spaces $CA - \{p\}$ and $A$ will have the same homotopy type. Does that imply $X \cup (CA - \{p\})$ will have the same homotopy type as that of $X\ $? If it is the case then we can say that $$H_n (X \cup (CA - \{p\}), CA - \{p\}) \approx H_n (X,A).$$ Do I ask it as a separate question?

Comment: Constructing a relative homotopy is the only way I believe, even when $X$ is a CW-complex, the pair $(X\cup (CA\backslash p))$ is not good pair, so we can not apply the theorem "$n$-th relative homology is the same as $n$-th reduced homology of the quotient."

Comment: Hatcher didn't mentioned it in his book. Can you please look at page no. 125 of Hatcher?

Comment: You need to prove at first this: for any map $F\colon (X\times I, A\times I)\to (Y,B)$ we have $F(-,0)_*=F(-,1)_*\colon H_n(X,A)\to H_n(Y,B)$ using homotopy invariance of homology. Now as a corollary(using five lemma on a ladder of two long exact sequences ), show for $A\subseteq A'\subseteq X$, if $A'$ is a deformation retract onto $X$, then the inclusion induced map $H_n(A', A)\to H_n(X,A)$ is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement in the beginning of your post is not true.

Think about if the total space is $[0,1]$ and $X = \mathbb Q \cap [0,1]$, $Y = ([0,1] - X) \cup \{0 \}$.

Then $X \cap Y = \{0\}$ which $Y$ trivially retracts onto. But $X \cup Y = [0,1]$ definitely does not retract onto $X = \mathbb Q \cap [0,1]$.

This is because retracts have to be surjective but there can be no surjective map from $[0,1]$ which is compact to a space $X$ which is not compact. $X$ is not compact since it's not closed as a subset of $\mathbb R$.

As for the pasting lemma: it will work if $X$ and $Y$ are either both open or both closed in $X \cup Y$.